# MVC framework Instances on different servers

Tags: model-view-controller

I am trying to build an application using spring MVC with Jboss, do I need to have the veiw(html/javascript) on the same Jboss server or it can reside outside the server?

Answer (score 0):

*MVC* is related to logical separation of concerns in an application. Different code layers take the responsibility of of being model, view and controller.
Where these layers reside physically depends upon the architecture you choose - more popularly known as *N-tiered* architecture. However in general the 3-tiered architecture is more preferred in internet based applications. The client (browser or other user-agent) resides on one machine, the application ( in your case developed using Spring MVC - with jsp/html/javascript/controller/business logic/data access code) deployed on one server and the data-store (database) deployed on another server. Within this there are multiple options like deploying your application on multiple servers for load-balancing/high availability but is entirely different concern. While technically there is nothing which stops you from putting your jsp/html/javascript on a different server but then you would need to put the controller there as well . So at most using Spring MVC you can put the view and controller on one server and model and business logic on another server. Also you would need the capability to invoke your business logic on a different machine. For such distributed applications EJB's have been the choice but in the last decade or so the distributed business logic model has been heavily discouraged because of it's failure in enterprise scale applications and is well documented.

So in your case I would suggest to keep the three layers in one server itself.